# GoSublime - possible to display documentation beside the code completion popup?

Tags: windows, go, sublimetext2

After i have written out a function in some package, it's possible to display it's documentation via

```
ctrl+dot,ctrl+h
```

Is it possible to view the documentation for each method in the code completion popup, without actually writing the statement out?

Comment: I think [Super User](http://superuser.com) is a better fit for this question.

Comment: @Tom Err... why? Sublime Text has a much healthier question & answer base on Stack Overflow ([tag 1](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sublimetext/info), [tag 2](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sublimetext2/info), [tag 3](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sublimetext3/info)) than it does on [Super User](http://superuser.com/tags/sublime-text-2/info).

Comment: @Tom also as this is about use in a development case i.e. code and its matching documentation this is explicitly on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. Also, you're better off opening an issue on the issue tracker https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime/issues/new . In addition to emailing me, it's fastest way to get in contact with me.